# VssPropertyValidationException : Not able to get Workitems using REST API in TFS 2017

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

I am new to working with TFS. Below is the code i am trying to execute for retrieving workitems of project and i get the error as below. Please suggest me if i am missing something. I am using TFS onpremise.

**{"$id":"1",
"innerException":null,
"message":"You must pass a query object in the body of the request.",
"typeName":"Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common.VssPropertyValidationException, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Common, Version=14.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a",
"typeKey":"VssPropertyValidationException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}**

```
var resturl = "tfs Server URL/tfs/collectionname/_apis/wit/wiql?api-version=1.0"

var query = "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc";

$.ajax({
   "url": resturl,
   "type": "POST", 
   "Content-type": "application/json",
   body: JSON.stringify(query),
   headers: {
      "Accept": "application/json"
   },
   success: function (data) {
       alert('success');
       },
   error: function (error) {
       alert('failure');
       alert(error.statusText);
       alert(error.responseJSON.message);
       }
  });
```

[Edit]: I am able to retrieve the list of projects from the REST API from the below code.

```
var resturl = "tfs Server URL/tfs/collectionname/_apis/projects?stateFilter=All"

$.ajax({
            "url": resturl,
            "type": "GET",
            "Content-type": "application/json",            
            headers: {
                "Accept": "application/json"
            },
            success: function (data) {                
                alert('success');
            },
            error: function (error) {
                alert('failure');
                alert(error.statusText);
                alert(error.responseJSON.message);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Issue fixed. Found the solution from [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/20b2e061-ce0b-4d42-812c-b44065745d05/tfs-restful-api-wiql-workitem-query-lanaguage?forum=tfsgeneral) forum. Very useful one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the wrong format, the `var query` is a **string format** not a **json format**. This is why you got the error `"You must pass a query object in the body of the request."`

You could refer this official tutorial **[Work item query language](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/wiql)**

```
POST https://{instance}/DefaultCollection/[{project}/]_apis/wit/wiql?api-version={version}

Content-type: application/json

{
  "query": string
}
```

So you need to use bleow format

```
var query = {"query": "Select [System.Id], [System.Title], [System.State] From WorkItems Where [System.WorkItemType] = 'Feature' order by [Microsoft.VSTS.Common.Priority] asc, [System.CreatedDate] desc"};
```